# Guardar datos desde una API en mi base de datos

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

En el proyecto que estoy realizando me veo en la necesidad de conectar cada 5 minutos a una API foránea, capturar los datos y guardarlos en una tabla de mi DB. ¿Alguna idea de como logar esto?

Estoy trabajando con Laravel 5.6

Comment: Crea un cron job para hacer una llamada a tu url ejecutora cada 5 minutos.

Te dejo un link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11375260/cron-command-to-run-url-address-every-5-minutes

Comment: Puedes usar **Task Scheduling** de Laravel Te permite crear un cron y establecerle el tiempo que necesites para cada ejecucion [Task Scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling)